# How to install pam_mount on Centos 8

Tags: linux, pam, centos8

Previously, I installed pam_mount by command

```
sudo yum -q -y install cifs-utils pam_mount
```

But now i get

```
Error: Unable to find a match: pam_mount
```

Help, please, how i can install pam_mount to CentOS 8?

Comment: Do you have the epel repo installed?

Comment: No, thanks for your help. I add epel repo and pam-mount was installed successfully.
But do you know why pam-mount missing from standard repositories on Centos?

As far as I know there is no need to connect additional repositories in fedora or ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Adding the epel repo should resolve your issue:

```
yun install epel-release
```

Comment: yum install epel-release